# How to write the contents of the console to a file in C++ or C, multiple process/exe may write to console

Tags: c++, c

I have multiple exes(one exe call other exe, another exe may call another....) which are writing something to console. I would like to copy the displayed contents of console to a text file. In C++ or C. not manually by right click and mark paste. If same happens through code it will be a great help.

C or C++

Comment: Show your code please :)

Comment: You don't need to [code this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: FILE *fp;

   fp = freopen("C:/Users/gir/Documents/out.txt", "a",stdout);

 /*freopen("C:\\Users\\dgirish\\Documents\\out.txt","a",stdout);*/
 cout<<" \nappending from parent \n";
  system("cmd /c start C:\\Users\\gir\\Documents\\TemplateHeaderOrsource");

  fclose(fp);

Answer (score 0):

Write the name of the exe file in the console/command prompt along with greater than symbol and the file name in which you want the output.

Ex. Considering "abc.exe" the executable file.

write the below statements in your cmd or console.

**abc.exe > output.txt**

This will create a file "**output.txt**" with the output, in the same folder where the **exe** file exists.